# Hierarchy of views

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

One of my xib files has a scrollview and an image view.  I was adding buttons to my image view (because I wanted them to scale when I zoomed), but nothing happens when I click them.  I am fairly certain that this is because the image view is in the scroll view, so I can't click the buttons.  When I add the buttons to the scroll view instead, I can click them, but they don't scale when I zoom.

What I need:  Buttons that I can click that will also scale when I zoom in and out.

What I think I need to do:  Add another view to put the buttons on.

What I don't know:  What the hierarchy of my views should be, to satisfy my needs.

I should add that I did all of this in code (not in IB).

---

EDIT:  the image view is within the scroll view

[image]

Comment: Is the image view contained in scrollview?

Comment: yes sorry it is.  I will edit that into the question

Comment: I tried it. The button should zoomable and clickable if you set it as a subview to image view. Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what I did was put a UIView as the only thing within the UIScrollView. This then became its contents.

Those contents are zoomable. Anything within that uiview also zooms. this should include any buttons, any imageviews or any other controls for that matter. Then you set contentSize and contentOffset on the scrollview to set the size of the "Content" it should be scrolling.

My scrollview has a UIView that is the content, therefore so I use the frame.size and frame.origin respectively to get the scrollview started.

My UIView is the same size as the UIScrollview and is anchored to the edges with flexible height and width.

Here is an image of my used scrollview.

[image]

As you can see, the scrollview only has one item within it. And everything else is within that.

I had the label in the Player View Scroll Contents as well. but then what is the point of a timer display that moves...

**Edit**

Here is the code I use for the viewForZoomingInScrollView:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView == self.playerScrollView){
        return self.playerViewScrollContents;
    }
    else if (scrollView == self.playerScrollView2){
        return self.playerView2ScrollContents;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

As you can see my item has 2 scrollviews and 2 contents. one for each scrollview.

Comment: Okay I have a few questions:

In `-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` should I return the scroll view?  

Also I am trying to add the new UIView too the scrollview, but Its not showing up in the hierarchy in the .xib file, does this mean its not working ?

Comment: in the viewForZoomingInScrollView: you return the ScrollContents. that would be the single view that is within the Scrollview. All its contents will scroll and zoom appropriately :)